# gcloud app deploy cannot find app.yaml if go.mod is in a different directory

Tags: go, google-app-engine, gcloud, app-engine-flexible

I have been unable to deploy my Go app to Google App Engine Flexible for a weeks now, although I don't remember changing anything relevant. The go.mod and go.sum files are in the top directory, while the app.yaml is in `./cmd/app/`.

Error message on `gcloud app deploy`:

```sh
Services to deploy:

descriptor:                  [/Users/me/go/src/github.com/me/project/cmd/app/app.yaml]
source:                      [/Users/me/go/src/github.com/me/project/cmd/app]
target project:              [project-us-central1]
target service:              [default]
target version:              [20220118t234216]
target url:                  [https://project-us-central1.uc.r.appspot.com]
target service account:      [App Engine default service account]


Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  

Beginning deployment of service [default]...

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Required file is not uploaded: [app.yaml]. 
This file should not be added to an ignore list 
(https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore)
```

(Of course, app.yaml has been never on the ignore list.)

I tried the following:

1. Add `!app.yaml` to [.gcloudignore file](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore)
2. Delete `.gcloudignore` file
3. `gcloud config set gcloudignore/enabled false`
4. Wait until a new version of `gcloud` is released (Google Cloud SKD 368.0.0).

Note that this happens both to my existing Go app which was deployed successfully many times over the last few years (the last time in November 2021), and also to a newly created simple web server app under the same directory structure. However, if I create a simple app without Go modules (go.mod, so.sum), `gcloud app deploy` works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of struggling it turned out that the issue was that the `./cmd/app/app.yaml` file was not in the same directory as the `./go.mod` and `./go.sum` files.

My workaround is renaming `go.mod` temporarily before invoking `gcloud app deploy`, and then moving it back once the deployment is done. That way everything works fine again.

Comment: I got this same error when following the Google Cloud Platform "Hello World!" tutorial. The github clone has the example code and app.yaml in subdirectories, and the go.mod and go.sum in the root. Deploy fails. I copied go.* files to the source code subdirectory and got more errors (gcc not found). I copied the app.yaml to the root and got build errors. However the original error is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a workaround while posting this question. Initially, this seems to be working:

```sh
gcloud app deploy --appyaml=app.yaml
```

However, after about 30 minutes the deployment always fails with the following error:

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.                                                                                  
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] The system encountered a fatal error
```

The deployed version seems to be running but it returns HTTP 404 for any request. After stopping and restarting the version in the Console, it's still non-functional: it returns mostly HTTP 502, and sometimes HTTP 503 and "Service error -27". I can see in the logs that /readiness_check calls all fail with 503, `failReason:"null"`

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is copying go.mod and go.sum to your working directory from where you are running gcloud app deploy command. This works for me.